# Boolean to string with lowercase

Tags: python, string, format, boolean, lowercase

Can the `str.format()` method print boolean arguments without capitalized strings?

I cannot use `str(myVar).lower()` as argument of format, because I want to preserve the case of the letters when `myVar` is not a boolean.

Please don't post solutions with conditional checks of the values of the variable.

All I am interested is in the possibility of writing the following:

```
"Bla bla bla {}".format(myVar)
```

so that the output becomes `"Bla bla bla true"` when `myVar == True` and `"Bla bla bla false"` when `myVar == false`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want lowercase booleans? Is this [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)-related, for example?

Comment: No, `str.format()` will not transform the case of boolean values; you'd need to do so manually. Why do you need this?

Comment: `if mybool: str = 'true' else: str = 'false'`

Comment: @Unihedron: `boolval = 'true' if mybool else 'false'`. Or just `str(mybool).lower()`..

Comment: @MartijnPieters My comment was not intended as an actual solution, just a hint to that the straightforward approach is to conditionally assign string based on boolean. I don't believe there's a library method for this. And it's not too difficult. Also for tubafranz, please take a [tour].

Comment: `"ftarlusee"[myVar::2]` for extra fun :)

Comment: OK, I just wanted to make sure I have to do it manually. I thought somehow it was possible to "configure" python to have such behaviour, because I wanted to avoid the logic of needed to detect the boolean and perform the lowering of the case. I need this particular behaviour in my code. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 19):

You could use an expression like this

```
str(myVar).lower() if type(myVar) is bool else myVar
```

Comment: `isinstance(myVar, bool)` is preferred, even if `bool` cannot be subclassed further.

Comment: `str(myVar).lower() if isinstance(myVar, bool) else myVar`

Answer (score 3):

Try a lambda that you can call:

```
>>> f = lambda x: str(x).lower() if isinstance(x, bool) else  x
>>> 'foo {} {}'.format(f(True), f('HELLO'))
'foo true HELLO'
```

Comment: As recommended in PEP8, better use `def f(x): return str(x).lower() if isinstance(x, bool) else  x` instead of lambda https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations